# ASP.Net, how to put hyperlinks in datagrids.

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, ssms

Hi i have a datagrid I've put in on a aspx web form in visual studio 2010, I'm new to this so I've been following the ms tutorials.

One of the columns on my data grid contains a lot of information, is there a way i can add a "+more" option in the cell next to the entry that shows only the first few characters of that cell, but once clicked  opens all the information on that particular entry but onto a new aspx form?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three different ways...

1. Structure your data object/query so that it returns a key and and abbreviation (i.e, first name, last name, id, bio) and use a template that turns id into a link.
2. Use the onrowbound event to manipulate the controls on the row, so that you have a href to your details page.
3. Use css to show the additional info on a hover/mouse over (I like this, but it doesn't play well with mobile devices, which don't have either event).

EDIT: Methods 1&3 would be done on your aspx page, method 2 would be done in the codebehind for your page.  Method 1 is really dependent upon your being able to control the data object/ query results.  If you are calling a stored proc that someone else controls, it may be very difficult to make it work.

Comment: is there anyway to do it using the, visual studio IDE?

Comment: @stefan: see my edit.  Whether it can be done on the aspx page or it has to be done on the code behind really depends upon what data you are getting and how.